# Find exactly what PHP files are responsible for each PHP process

Tags: linux, memory, php, io

I have a WordPress website hosted on a shared Red Hat 4.4.7-18 Linux box, and from time to time I get huge memory and I/O spikes exceeding my allowed memory limit, making my website unresponsive.

I have cPanel installed, but there is no way I can find out exactly what process is causing this but only seeing those spikes.

I think this is being caused by one of my plugins and would really want to know which of them does that. I have 15+ plugins installed, so enabling/disabling each one and monitoring if the issue still exists is not an option, as this apparently happens randomly.

I can SSH into my box and I would like to know if there is a way I can find what PHP file is behind each of the PHP processes I see either when running `ps -aux | less` or when I visit the **PHP Processes** option from my cPanel.

Knowing this information I could easily identify what plugin/script is causing those memory spikes.

cPanel PHP Processes:
[image: cPanel PHP Processes]

At the time of the screenshot, the spikes are gone and I only have 3 PHP processes running; but would like, for example, to know who is behind the PHP process ID 59222.

Running `ps` with no options will show just the processes on my terminal:

```
    PID TTY          TIME CMD
 612676 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
 703305 pts/0    00:00:00 ps
```

Doing a `ps -u -p59222` will show:

```
Warning: bad syntax, perhaps a bogus '-'? See /usr/share/doc/procps-3.2.8/FAQ
USER         PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
```

But a `ps -aux | grep '[5]9222'` will get:

```
Warning: bad syntax, perhaps a bogus '-'? See /usr/share/doc/procps-3.2.8/FAQ
myusername 59222  3.8  0.1 301620 44068  ?          S 01:33   0:57 /usr/bin/php
```

I am a beginner and don’t know much about this stuff but learning my way,
so please be extremely explicit in any suggestions you offer,
because I can’t understand jargon
like “What does `ps` tell you about the processes?”

Comment: What does `ps` tell you about the processes? What do you get when you say `ps -u -p59222` or ``ps -aux | grep '[5]9222'``? Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: And what does that mean?

Comment: First of all, take it easy as I am a beginner and don't know much about this stuff but learning my way out. Now the `ps` command's output is correct and should not show the _output for the PHP processes (that cPanel reports)_ as you say you're expecting but only the _four items of information for at least two processes currently on the system: the shell and ps_ as I found in the online documentation. When doing `ps -aux | less` I get pretty much the same PID, User and Process path (/usr/bin/php) as the cpanel shows.

Comment: Doind `ps -aux | grep '[5]9222'  (with a space) will show 'Warning: bad syntax, perhaps a bogus '-'? See /usr/share/doc/procps-3.2.8/FAQ
myusername  59222  3.8  0.1 301620 44068 ?        S    01:33   0:57 /usr/bin/php` so yes, I'm askig you: What does all that mean and how running all those ps commands will help me identify the php files behind those processes?

Comment: I’m sorry, but “What is the meaning of life, Unix, and everything?” is too broad a question for [SE].  There are approximately 42,000 books about Unix; I’ve heard that [O’Reilly](https://www.oreilly.com) has some good ones (I am *not* associated with O’Reilly).  (But you might also want to look at `/usr/share/doc/procps-3.2.8/FAQ`, as suggested by the error message you’ve been getting.)  If you’re an ESL beginner (just learning English), I suggest that you mention that; it might get you some extra consideration / sympathy / pity. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  I was hoping that `ps` would give us useful information about the processes, that would help to answer your question, but apparently it reports each PHP process as ```/usr/bin/php``` with no additional information, which is not helpful.  So I don’t really know what else to suggest.